# How can I find the relationship between MetadataComponentId and the expected name for the Metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, tooling-api, tooling, dependency-api

I've been using the [Dependency API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm) to try to retrieve all dependencies for a given metadata.

I would like to get a list of dependencies, and then retrieve these with the Metadata API.
**Unfortunately, I can't find an easy way to get the expected Metadata API name from the MetadataComponentId returned from the Dependency API.**

For instance, with the following Dependency API results:

[image]

Both fields (RefMetadataComponentName) have the same name, but not the same Id: they are fields from separate sObjects.
So the related name expected by the Metadata API would be the following:
 - `MyCustomObject__c.My_Custom_Field__c`
 - `MySecondCustomObjet__c.My_Custom_Field__c`.

How can I get this from the MetadataComponentId ?
I tried to use the Tooling API to query directly a table with the same name as the MetadataComponentType (quite naive, right ?):
`Select DeveloperName from CustomField where Id = 'xxxx'`

This doesn't work because some tables have a `DeveloperName` field, some other will have a `Name` or `FullName`, anyway nothing is consistent.

Moreover, I'm not getting the parent sObject name, just a `TableEnumOrId` field, and it looks like you need another query to get the sObject name. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customfield.htm

Also, some other RefMetadataComponentType doesn't exist as Tooling API tables (NavigationMenu, ListView, StandardEntity...).

In this specific example, I also tried to query `FieldDefinition`, but while I tried to field on `DurableId` or `EntityDefinitionId` with the `RefMetadataComponentId`, I didn't get any result (not easy to understand which Id is the same as which one).

Have I any other solution than to hardcode everything for each MetadataComponentType:
- which table to query (maybe more than 1)
- which query to use
- hardcode a few other stuff (add `__c` at the end of a custom field, after of course finding a way to know if the field is custom or not).

Comment: If you take the `RefMetadataComponentID` and use that in a new query as the `MetadataComponentId` you could find the corresponding `MetadataComponentName`. It wouldn't be efficient, but it would line up with how the dependency API determines names and allow you to distinguish which custom object My_Custom_Field belongs to.